# Editor's mail with no reviewer's comment

Tags: publications, peer-review, editors

Recently I submitted second revision of my manuscript in a highly reputed mathematics journal. My first revision was a major revision while the second one was a minor (with some terms like paper is ready to be published). After submitting my second revision I got an email from the editorial board which asked for further revisions of my manuscript. But, what is troubling me is that there were not reviewer comments in the mail. Also there were no attached files with reviewers comments.

Edit: I took only three days to resubmit my second minor revision and after another five days I got this mail with  no reviewers comment.
Also, there is only one reviewer for this manuscript.

Edit: At the end of the mail that I received it is written that "Reviewer's comment"  but it is showing blank. Submission status is "submission needing revision" (Revise). But I am not able to find the reviewers comments.

I am worried. How come this is possible?

Comment: It looks like the editor forgot to attach the reviews. Ask for them.

Comment: Somebody has down voted with no suggestions. If the question is not suitable for the community I would be glad to delete this question.

Comment: Downvotes without explanations happen, sadly.  In any case, I don't believe you can delete your questions when there is an upvoted answer.

Comment: I want to know whether or not the editor forgot to attach the reviews.?

Comment: @srijan Any updates on what actually happened? I am curious as well.

Comment: What happened in the end? I have received the same mistake mail. Asking for a revision withouth reviewers' comments!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of trying to second-guess what might have happened you should simply contact the editors and ask what revisions they wish to see you perform. The reasons for the lack of information could be any of the suggestions given but could also be a mistake, an attachment that was not passed on or a mail sent by one person who has not seen your recently provided update, the list of possibilities is long.

So, e-mail the editor or journal and briefly explain what you received and how the lack of information makes revisions impossible.

Answer (score 8):

My interpretation: after the first revision, both referees wrote that the remaining changes were minor. So the editor did not send the paper back to them but took a quick glance himself/herself to make sure they had been fixed. While doing this, he/she noticed a few more small mistakes and asked you to make these final changes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I even didn't get editor's comment. At the end of the mail it is written that "Reviewer's comment" but it is blank. I will edit my question gain.

Comment: I still don't get the complete timeline, it would be good if you could explain in detail what happened. But if all you got is a mail saying "make these changes" and then no suggested changes, the simplest explanation is that someone forgot an attachment. :)

Comment: Thanks again.  Ya same thing happened. Editor's mail says  "Reviewers have now commented on your paper. You will see that they are advising that you revise your manuscript. If you are prepared to undertake the work required, I would be pleased to reconsider my decision." But, i didnt receive any commments of reviewer.

Comment: @srijan Does the editor's message say something like "we cannot accept your manuscript as is."  In that case, it may be a poorly worded rejection.  Either way, a short email to the editor asking if there were additional reviewer comments should answer you question.

Comment: @Kimball It says nothing like that. I have mentioned that editors comment says that revise your manuscript.

Comment: @srijan In that case the "I would be pleased to reconsider my decision" phrase is rather perplexing.  Maybe you should let us know what the end result was.

Comment: @Kimball I will surely let you know :).

Comment: @Kimball That paper is accepted. Thanks for your concern. :)

Comment: For this like this you really should directly ask the people involved, instead of us.